# Run Length Encoding in Go(lang)

Tags: go

[Run-length encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) is a simple form of data compression, where runs (consecutive data elements) are replaced by just one data value and a count.

For example:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

becomes this:

```
12W1B12W3B24W1B14W
```

Here's an implementation of `RunLengthEncode` and `RunLengthDecode` functions in Go. I'd appreciate any feedback. What's OK, what's not, and what could be improved and/or changed.

```
package encode

import (
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

type runLength struct {
    enc, dec func(string) string
}

func newRunLength() *runLength {
    return &runLength{
        enc: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                firstLetter := input[0]
                inputLength := len(input)
                input = strings.TrimLeft(input, string(firstLetter))
                if counter := inputLength - len(input); counter > 1 {
                    result.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(counter))
                }
                result.WriteString(string(firstLetter))
            }
            return result.String()
        },
        dec: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                letterIndex := strings.IndexFunc(input, func(r rune) bool {return !unicode.IsDigit(r)})
                multiply := 1
                if letterIndex != 0 {
                    multiply, _ = strconv.Atoi(input[:letterIndex])
                }
                result.WriteString(strings.Repeat(string(input[letterIndex]), multiply))
                input = input[letterIndex+1:]
            }
            return result.String()
        }}
}

func (rl runLength) encode(input string) string {
    return rl.enc(input)
}

func (rl runLength) decode(input string) string {
    return rl.dec(input)
}

func RunLengthEncode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().encode(input)
}

func RunLengthDecode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().decode(input)
}
```

**Test cases:**

```
package encode

// run-length encode a string
var encodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"", "", "empty string"},
    {"XYZ", "XYZ", "single characters only are encoded without count"},
    {"AABBBCCCC", "2A3B4C", "string with no single characters"},
    {"WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB", "12WB12W3B24WB", "single characters mixed with repeated characters"},
    {"  hsqq qww  ", "2 hs2q q2w2 ", "multiple whitespace mixed in string"},
    {"aabbbcccc", "2a3b4c", "lowercase characters"},
}

// run-length decode a string
var decodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"", "", "empty string"},
    {"XYZ", "XYZ", "single characters only"},
    {"2A3B4C", "AABBBCCCC", "string with no single characters"},
    {"12WB12W3B24WB", "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB", "single characters with repeated characters"},
    {"2 hs2q q2w2 ", "  hsqq qww  ", "multiple whitespace mixed in string"},
    {"2a3b4c", "aabbbcccc", "lower case string"},
}

// encode and then decode
var encodeDecodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"zzz ZZ  zZ", "zzz ZZ  zZ", "encode followed by decode gives original string"},
}
```

**Tests:**

```
package encode

import "testing"

func TestRunLengthEncode(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range encodeTests {
        if actual := RunLengthEncode(test.input); actual != test.expected {
            t.Errorf("FAIL %s - RunLengthEncode(%s) = %q, expected %q.",
                test.description, test.input, actual, test.expected)
        }
        t.Logf("PASS RunLengthEncode - %s", test.description)
    }
}
func TestRunLengthDecode(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range decodeTests {
        if actual := RunLengthDecode(test.input); actual != test.expected {
            t.Errorf("FAIL %s - RunLengthDecode(%s) = %q, expected %q.",
                test.description, test.input, actual, test.expected)
        }
        t.Logf("PASS RunLengthDecode - %s", test.description)
    }
}
func TestRunLengthEncodeDecode(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range encodeDecodeTests {
        if actual := RunLengthDecode(RunLengthEncode(test.input)); actual != test.expected {
            t.Errorf("FAIL %s - RunLengthDecode(RunLengthEncode(%s)) = %q, expected %q.",
                test.description, test.input, actual, test.expected)
        }
        t.Logf("PASS %s", test.description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a real-world code review: Code should be correct, maintainable, robust, reasonably efficient, and, most importantly, readable.

---

The Go programming language was designed for simplicity and readability. Why did you write:

```
type runLength struct {
    enc, dec func(string) string
}

func newRunLength() *runLength {
    return &runLength{
        enc: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                firstLetter := input[0]
                inputLength := len(input)
                input = strings.TrimLeft(input, string(firstLetter))
                if counter := inputLength - len(input); counter > 1 {
                    result.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(counter))
                }
                result.WriteString(string(firstLetter))
            }
            return result.String()
        },
        dec: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                letterIndex := strings.IndexFunc(input, func(r rune) bool { return !unicode.IsDigit(r) })
                multiply := 1
                if letterIndex != 0 {
                    multiply, _ = strconv.Atoi(input[:letterIndex])
                }
                result.WriteString(strings.Repeat(string(input[letterIndex]), multiply))
                input = input[letterIndex+1:]
            }
            return result.String()
        }}
}

func (rl runLength) encode(input string) string {
    return rl.enc(input)
}

func (rl runLength) decode(input string) string {
    return rl.dec(input)
}

func RunLengthEncode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().encode(input)
}

func RunLengthDecode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().decode(input)
}
```

when a simpler, more readable form is:

```
func RunLengthEncode(input string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    for len(input) > 0 {
        firstLetter := input[0]
        inputLength := len(input)
        input = strings.TrimLeft(input, string(firstLetter))
        if counter := inputLength - len(input); counter > 1 {
            result.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(counter))
        }
        result.WriteString(string(firstLetter))
    }
    return result.String()
}

func RunLengthDecode(input string) string {
    var result strings.Builder
    for len(input) > 0 {
        letterIndex := strings.IndexFunc(input, func(r rune) bool { return !unicode.IsDigit(r) })
        multiply := 1
        if letterIndex != 0 {
            multiply, _ = strconv.Atoi(input[:letterIndex])
        }
        result.WriteString(strings.Repeat(string(input[letterIndex]), multiply))
        input = input[letterIndex+1:]
    }
    return result.String()
}
```

---

Go was designed and implemented to be reasonably efficient. Your code looks inefficient.

For example,

baduker:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -run=!
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkEncode-4    614804   1936 ns/op   464 B/op   27 allocs/op
BenchmarkDecode-4    844690   1446 ns/op   256 B/op   18 allocs/op
$
```

versus peterSO:

```
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -run=!
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkEncode-4   3543656    342 ns/op   104 B/op    4 allocs/op
BenchmarkDecode-4   2717763    460 ns/op   216 B/op    7 allocs/op
$
```

`benchmark_test.go`:

```
package encode

import (
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkEncode(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        RunLengthEncode("AABCCCDEEEE")
        RunLengthEncode("WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB")
    }
}

func BenchmarkDecode(b *testing.B) {
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        RunLengthDecode("2AB3CD4E")
        RunLengthDecode("12WB12W3B24WB")
    }
}
```

peterSO `run_length_encoding.go`:

```
package encode

import (
    "strconv"
)

func RunLengthEncode(s string) string {
    e := make([]byte, 0, len(s))
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        c := s[i]
        j := i + 1
        for ; j <= len(s); j++ {
            if j < len(s) && s[j] == c {
                continue
            }
            if j-i > 1 {
                e = strconv.AppendInt(e, int64(j-i), 10)
            }
            e = append(e, c)
            break
        }
        i = j - 1
    }
    return string(e)
}

func RunLengthDecode(s string) string {
    d := make([]byte, 0, len(s))
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        n := 0
        for ; i < len(s) && (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'); i++ {
            n = 10*n + int(s[i]-'0')
        }
        if i < len(s) {
            c := s[i]
            for ; n > 1; n-- {
                d = append(d, c)
            }
            d = append(d, c)
        }
    }
    return string(d)
}
```

baduker `run_length_encoding.go`:

```
package encode

import (
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

type runLength struct {
    enc, dec func(string) string
}

func newRunLength() *runLength {
    return &runLength{
        enc: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                firstLetter := input[0]
                inputLength := len(input)
                input = strings.TrimLeft(input, string(firstLetter))
                if counter := inputLength - len(input); counter > 1 {
                    result.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(counter))
                }
                result.WriteString(string(firstLetter))
            }
            return result.String()
        },
        dec: func(input string) string {
            var result strings.Builder
            for len(input) > 0 {
                letterIndex := strings.IndexFunc(input, func(r rune) bool { return !unicode.IsDigit(r) })
                multiply := 1
                if letterIndex != 0 {
                    multiply, _ = strconv.Atoi(input[:letterIndex])
                }
                result.WriteString(strings.Repeat(string(input[letterIndex]), multiply))
                input = input[letterIndex+1:]
            }
            return result.String()
        }}
}

func (rl runLength) encode(input string) string {
    return rl.enc(input)
}

func (rl runLength) decode(input string) string {
    return rl.dec(input)
}

func RunLengthEncode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().encode(input)
}

func RunLengthDecode(input string) string {
    return newRunLength().decode(input)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yet another no-nonsense review. This is good stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation quickly falls apart when we have digits inside strings. Consider the following testcases:

```
package encode

// run-length encode a string
var encodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"1111111111111", "131", "numbers test"},
    {"131", "131", "unique numbers test"},
}

// run-length decode a string
var decodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"131", "1111111111111", "numbers test"},
    {"131", "131", "unique numbers test"},
}

// encode and then decode
var encodeDecodeTests = []struct {
    input       string
    expected    string
    description string
}{
    {"1111111111111", "1111111111111", "encode followed by decode gives original string"},
    {"131", "131", "encode followed by decode gives original string"},
}
```

These requirements are impossible to satisfy as two distinct inputs can give the same output. When actually run, a panic results:

```
--- FAIL: TestRunLengthDecode (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 19 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1(0xc0000a4300)
        /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/testing/testing.go:792 +0x387
panic(0x512100, 0x619ff0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
encode.newRunLength.func2(0x536b33, 0x3, 0x5207a0, 0xc00005e4b0)
        /home/minombre/go/src/encode/encode.go:34 +0x2eb
encode.runLength.decode(0x53fb70, 0x53fb80, 0x536b33, 0x3, 0xc000030601, 0x40bbf8)
        /home/minombre/go/src/encode/encode.go:48 +0x3a
encode.RunLengthDecode(0x536b33, 0x3, 0x6074c8, 0x27)
        /home/minombre/go/src/encode/encode.go:56 +0x4f
encode.TestRunLengthDecode(0xc0000a4300)
        /home/minombre/go/src/encode/encode_test.go:16 +0xee
testing.tRunner(0xc0000a4300, 0x53fb58)
        /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/testing/testing.go:827 +0xbf
created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/testing/testing.go:878 +0x35c
FAIL    encode  0.008s
```

You could possibly store these into some sort of a structure with a character per structure but that would be impractical.